# returned 404 error when load js file

Tags: javascript, html, go

I get an error when i would like to render html file which contains a script link on js file.
But when i load page i get this error :

```
Started GET "/views/script.js" .... Returning 404
```

my folder is like this

```
|--todolist 
   |--main.go
   |--views/
      |--index.html
      |--script.js
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/zenazn/goji"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func renderHTMLPage(w http.ResponseWriter, path string) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderHTMLPage(w, "./views/index.html")
}

func main() {
        goji.Get("/", Index)
        goji.Serve()
}
```

views/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Le titre du document</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

<h1>To-Do List </h1>
<ul id="todolist">
<li> Hello <button>Delete</button></li>
<li> Wesh <button>Delete</button></li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="new-text" /><button id="add">Add</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

views/script.js

```
function addListItem() {
    var text = $('#new-text').val()
    if (text != "") {
        $('#todolist').append('<li>'+text+'<button id="dede" name=\"' + i + '\">Delete</button></li>')
    }
    $('#new-text').val("")
}

function deleteItem() {
    $(this).parent().remove()
}


$(function() {

    $('#add').on('click', addListItem);

    $("#todolist").on("click", "#dede", deleteItem)

});
```

How can I do to make it properly load the js file ?

And what is the best way to create an app who use only jquery/javascript with a golang api on architecture ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either:

- Serve from the directory containing `/views` - e.g. goji.Get("/views/*", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/Users/matt/Desktop/views/")))`
- Use [`http.StripPrefix`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix) (recommended)

The below allows you to decouple the path from the directory name:

```
func main() {
    goji.Get("/views/*", http.StripPrefix("/views", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/Users/matt/Desktop/views/"))))
    goji.Get("/", Index)
    goji.Serve()
}
```

I'd recommend against serving from the 'root' - `/*`. Better to serve from a dedicated assets path as it makes it easier when looking at caching, interacting with CDNs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case code should look like

```
goji.Get("/", Index)
goji.Get("/*", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./views")))
goji.Serve()
```

But I must say keeping template and static files in same directory is bad idea as well as serving static files from root.

Comment: @Fantasim put all static files into `assets` folder like `assets/js`, `assets/css`, etc, and replace `goji.Get("/*", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./views")))` with `goji.Get("/assets/*", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets")))` would be good start. So you will be able to work on app routes without thinking about conflicts between static file names and your dynamic parts.